# test YouTube Data API in real server

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to use YouTube data API for searching videos in Python. I have read full tutorial and I am able to authorize and authenticate the user from the local machine, But when I deployed the same code in the server I am getting bellow listed errors in logs. and browser displays 'Internal server error'

```
[ N 2019-02-01 04:12:09.9860 4335/Tq age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1117 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 20744, application /home/pricemon/YT_VDO_search_1 (production)
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 262, in parse_authorization_code_response
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 203, in parse_request_uri_response
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 208, in fetch_token

App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/YT_VDO_search_1/one.py", line 88, in oauth2callback
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
App 20744 output:   File "/home/pricemon/virtualenv/YT__VDO__search__1/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
```

I am trying the coed from [This guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps)

I have replaced the redirected URL path in the Google API console.

Bellow is my code.

```
def oauth2callback():
  # Specify the state when creating the flow in the callback so that it can
  # verified in the authorization server response.
  state = flask.session['state']

  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  # Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  # Store credentials in the session.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))
```

I am getting error when I fetch token using command `flow.fetch_token`

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/zd6dl5ZMNyA) from Google forum?

Comment: Yes, I have seen the thread but it does not state any solution. It says that I should check the version but I am running the same versions on the both local and server.

Comment: I am getting error when I fetch the token. I am unable to fetch the token while running the code on server side.

Comment: Please do check your implementation of OAuth.  If the access token request is invalid, such as the redirect URL didn’t match the one used during authorization, then the server needs to return an error response.